# How to convert javassist instance into instance of a specific domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I would like to intersect two lists of instances of a specific domain class using grails 1.3.7.

The problem is, that the instances of one list are created by javasisst so that the result of the intersection is always an empty list.

Here are my domains:

```
class User {
    ...
    static hasMany = [foos : Foo]
    ...
} 

class Foo {
    ...
    static hasMany = [bars : Bar]
    ...
}

class Bar {
    ...
    static hasMany = [localizedTitles : LocalizedTitle]
    ...
}
```

I get the list of all `Bar` instances of the user like this:

```
def allBarsOfUser = userInstance.foos.bars.flatten()
```

And try to intersect with another list of `Bar` instances:

```
def intersectedBars = bars.intersect(allBarsOfUser)
```

The problem is, that the type of elements of `allBarsOfUser` ist `Bar_$$_javassist_139` and the the type of the elememts of `bars` is `Bar` so that `intersectedBars` is always `[]`.

I solved my problem by doing the following - but I don't like the solution:

```
def allBarsOfUser = userInstance.foos.bars.flatten().collect{Bar.get(it.id)}
```

What would be a better solution?

How could I cast `Bar_$$_javassist_139` to `Bar` so that `intersect()` works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you're actually trying to do.  The `intersect` method ultimately relies on `equals`, so if you implement `equals` and `hashCode` in `Bar` then it will do what you want.  But you shouldn't generally implement `equals` in terms of the object ID, as IDs are only assigned when an object is saved so you wouldn't be able to compare a newly-created object with a previously-saved one.  Hibernate recommends that you [implement it based on a business key](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) (something that isn't the generated ID but which is stable and unlikely to change throughout the lifetime of the object)

```
class UserAccount {
  String username
  String realname

  public boolean equals(that) {
    return ((that instanceof UserAccount)
        && (this.username == that.username))
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    username.hashCode()
  }
}
```

So if you do want an ID comparison then it's clearer to do that explicitly.

```
def userBarIds = allBarsOfUser*.id
def intersectedBars = bars.findAll { it.id in userBarIds }
```

Comment: The ID comparison is sufficient here. It is nevertheless possible to cast a javassist class?

Comment: The javassist proxy _is_ an `instanceof Bar`, the point is that a proxy for the `Bar` with id 5 isn't the same object (`==` in the Java sense) as `Bar.get(5)`.  There is `GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy` but you shouldn't unwrap proxies explicitly unless you really have to, as doing so will cause an additional SQL query against the database.